# How to use scripts to get select information already on the page to another part of the page

Tags: javascript, java, html

My page has displays a list of NFL players along with some information next to them and an add button. My goal it to display all the players that have been added table next to the original. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAXMF.png)
this is what I have. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIMGy.png) And this would be my idea outcome if the add buttons were pressed next to Peyton Manning and Jamaal Charles. (Can't post images)

Here is the code that displays the players in a table.

```
<% int count = 0; 
   ArrayList<String[]> p = new ArrayList<String[]>();
   GetPlayers getplayers = new GetPlayers();
   String[][] result = getplayers.run();
   String[][] myList = new String[100][10];
%>

 <% for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)  { %>

<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"><button onclick="myFunction2(<%=i%>)"id="add<%= i %>">Add</button><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Position<%= i %>"><%= result[i][1] %><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Player<%= i %>"><%= result[i][3]+" "+result[i][4] %><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Team<%= i %>"><%= result[i][7] %><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Opponent<%= i %>"><%= result[i][8] %><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Projected<%= i %>"><%= result[i][5] %><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;"id="Salary<%= i %>"><%= result[i][2] %><br></td>
<tr>

<%} %>
```

Comment: Did you tried any javascript in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wooo Java Server Pages!

Add another `<table>` to display your selections in and give it an id (such as 'selected-players')

Add an id to your listing table rows `<tr>` (such as `id='player-listing-<%= i %>'`)

`myFunction2(i)` should then work something like:

```
myFunction2 = function (i){
  //get selection table
  var table = document.getElementById('selected-players');

  //get the row to be copied over
  var copyRow = document.getElementById('player-listing-'+i).cloneNode(true);

  //change the id attribute on the copied row
  copyRow.setAttribute('id', 'selected-row-'+i);

  //remove the add button on the copy (<td> and <button>)
  copyRow.removeChild(copyRow.firstChild);  
  copyRow.removeChild(copyRow.firstChild);

  //add copied row to new table
  table.appendChild(copyRow);
}
```

It may also help you to get used to the jQuery library as it can greatly simplify DOM manipulations such as this

=========================Edit for comment==============================

To retrieve the data back out of your table you need to go through it, and pull out the required data, then push it to an array.
The function below will do that and return a javascript array containing all the player names from the selected table, which you can then pass to your Java code

```
getPlayerNames = function(){
  var selected = document.querySelectorAll("#selected-players > tr > td");
  var playernames = [];
  for(var i=0; i<selected.length; ++i){
     var id = selected[i].getAttribute('id');
     if (id.indexOf('Player')>-1) {
         playernames.push(selected[i].textContent);
     }

  }
  return playernames;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you  very much this worked. To add on to my question I now need to extract the information from the selected-players table. Lets say I needed all the players names from the selected-players table in an array that I can pass into a java function. How would I do that?

Comment: I edited the original answer to give you an example of retrieving player name data from the table.  Good luck

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm still unsure how to use that javascript array in my java code. 
Lets say I wanted do something like this '<%String[] players = getPlayerNames(); %>' That doesn't work but what do i have to do to make that work?

Comment: The java code has already executed on the server side, so you can't directly assign javascript variables to it, as this executes client side, in the browser.
You need to pass the returned javascript array back to your server using a form submission or ajax request.

Comment: Hi @DanS. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.
Thanks and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

A simple example to show the approach to achieve what you want is implemented.
I hope this will help

```js
function myfunction(buttonElement){
 var htmlToAdd = buttonElement.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('table2').innerHTML += '<tr>'+htmlToAdd+'</tr>';
}
```

```css
#table2 button{
 display:none;
}
table{
float:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button onclick="myfunction(this)">this</button>
        </td>
      <td>Name1
        </td>
      <td>Age1
        </td>
      <td>Type1
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button onclick="myfunction(this)">this</button>
        </td>
      <td>Name2
        </td>
      <td>Age2
        </td>
      <td>Type2
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button onclick="myfunction(this)">this</button>
        </td>
      <td>Name3
        </td>
      <td>Age3
        </td>
      <td>Type3
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>

<table id="table2">
  </table>
```

Comment: I'm not familial with what is going on with the second snippet of code. What is that and where/how am I suppose to implement that in my code?

Comment: are you talking about the css part